# How can I convert text in an Emacs buffer, to a .odt file, from there usable by LibreOffice?

Tags: software-recommendation

Assume I've got an ordinary text file in an Emacs buffer. I want to convert it to a .odt
file, possibly adding italics and/or boldface characters. From lisp I can do anything
Emacs can do; also, I can pass bash commands to a bash window, as needed. Once I've
created the .odt version I assume LibreOffice can be used without too much aggravation.
How do you suggest I proceed?

Comment: please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly in particular, the version of ubuntu you are using and your versions of Emacs and LO. Why can't you just open LO Write and `paste` the text?

Answer (score 2):

To convert plain text in a text buffer to an `.odt` file, you will need to study the file format of the `.odt` file format. Essentially, an `.odt` is a zip-compressed file, containing text and graphics of the document organized in a specified folder structure. Thus, that will require some research from your part and some Lisp programming if nobody did this before and published the code.

Ask yourself whether there are likely better ways. If you save to a plain text file, you will be able to open it in LibreOffice without effort. Text could also be copied to the clipboard and pasted.

Answer (score 2):

I do this often. Copy the text into Emacs's kill buffer (<kbd>ESC < ESC > ESC w</kbd>), open a LibreOffice text document, Paste.

Much easier than trying to generate `.odt` format inside Emacs.

Comment: I should have said: part of my copied text was italicized [italic text property applied]. The